# Chrome DevTools port forwarding doesn't work for high port numbers

Tags: android, google-chrome, port, google-chrome-devtools, portforwarding

[image]

When debugging web applications on Android the port forwarding feature of Chrome DevTools works fine for ports with low numbers. However, high port numbers (such as 51262) does not work for me. How does one get high port numbers working?

By default Visual Studio uses such high numbers for web applications. It would be convenient not to have to change ports in the Visual Studio projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android USB Debugging Port Forward Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836574/android-usb-debugging-port-forward-error)

Comment: I am amazed this issue hasn't been addressed even after ore than two years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port Forwarding for ports 32768 to 65535 now works, as of October 24, 2017. You'll see the fix in Chrome 64. Check `chrome://version` to see what version of Chrome you're on. Chrome auto-updates to a new major version every 6 weeks.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688050