# Android USB Debugging Port Forward Error

Tags: android, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, portforwarding, android-remoteview

I am having a problem with the android remote debug port forwarding.  I need to get ports in the 44300-44399 range forward because visual studio debugging only allows SSL on those ports, but I can never get those ports to forward even though the documentation says it should work on any port from 1024-65535.  Anyone encountered this or know how I can figure out why the port isn't forwarded?  I know the connection is there since other ports work ok.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this in the [Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=322245).  Apparently only 1024-10000 is allowed despite the docs in chrome saying otherwise.  Checking to see if they are open to expanding the allowed range to the full spectrum.

Comment: Confirmed here.  I had a site on port 56004 which had the same problem you describe.  Moving it to 5604 fixed the issue.

Comment: I've filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688050 to request the expansion of range